# How to autostart this slide

Tags: jquery, slideshow, autostart

Hello there: first of all i have no idea on coding or anything related, simple question: is there any simple way to tell this code to autostart the slide? at the current moment the images change on click.
currently the index page only have one image, what i want is to add a few but without the need to click to see the next one
here is the code from my index:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    /*
    the images preload plugin
    */
    (function($) {
        $.fn.preload = function(options) {
            var opts    = $.extend({}, $.fn.preload.defaults, options),
                o       = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, this.data()) : opts;
            var c       = this.length,
                l       = 0;
            return this.each(function() {
                var $i  = $(this);
                $('<img/>').load(function(i){
                    ++l;
                    if(l == c) o.onComplete();
                }).attr('src',$i.attr('src'));  
            });
        };
        $.fn.preload.defaults = {
            onComplete  : function(){return false;}
        };
    })(jQuery);
//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        var $tf_bg              = $('#tf_bg'),
            $tf_bg_images       = $tf_bg.find('img'),
            $tf_bg_img          = $tf_bg_images.eq(0),
            $tf_thumbs          = $('#tf_thumbs'),
            total               = $tf_bg_images.length,
            current             = 0,
            $tf_content_wrapper = $('#tf_content_wrapper'),
            $tf_next            = $('#tf_next'),
            $tf_prev            = $('#tf_prev'),
            $tf_loading         = $('#tf_loading');

        //preload the images                
        $tf_bg_images.preload({
            onComplete  : function(){
                $tf_loading.hide();
                init();
            }
        });

        //shows the first image and initializes events
        function init(){
            //get dimentions for the image, based on the windows size
            var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
            //set the returned values and show the image
            $tf_bg_img.css({
                width   : dim.width,
                height  : dim.height,
                left    : dim.left,
                top     : dim.top
            }).fadeIn();

            //resizing the window resizes the $tf_bg_img
            $(window).bind('resize',function(){
                var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                $tf_bg_img.css({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    left    : dim.left,
                    top     : dim.top
                });
            });

            //expand and fit the image to the screen
            $('#tf_zoom').live('click',
                function(){
                    if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                        return false;

                    var $this   = $(this);
                    if($this.hasClass('tf_zoom')){
                        resize($tf_bg_img);
                        $this.addClass('tf_fullscreen')
                             .removeClass('tf_zoom');
                    }
                    else{
                        var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                        $tf_bg_img.animate({
                            width   : dim.width,
                            height  : dim.height,
                            top     : dim.top,
                            left    : dim.left
                        },350);
                        $this.addClass('tf_zoom')
                             .removeClass('tf_fullscreen'); 
                    }
                }
            );

            //click the arrow down, scrolls down
            $tf_next.bind('click',function(){
                if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                    return false;
                    scroll('tb');
            });

            //click the arrow up, scrolls up
            $tf_prev.bind('click',function(){
                if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                    return false;
                scroll('bt');
            });

            //mousewheel events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up
            $(document).mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
                if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                    return false;

                if(delta > 0)
                    scroll('bt');
                else
                    scroll('tb');
                return false;
            });

            //key events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up
            $(document).keydown(function(e){
                if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                    return false;

                switch(e.which){
                    case 38:    
                        scroll('bt');
                        break;  
                    case 40:    
                        scroll('tb');
                        break;
                }
            });
        }

        //show next / prev image
        function scroll(dir){
            //if dir is "tb" (top -> bottom) increment current, 
            //else if "bt" decrement it
            current = (dir == 'tb')?current + 1:current - 1;

            //we want a circular slideshow, 
            //so we need to check the limits of current
            if(current == total) current = 0;
            else if(current < 0) current = total - 1;

            //flip the thumb
            $tf_thumbs.flip({
                direction   : dir,
                speed       : 400,
                onBefore    : function(){
                    //the new thumb is set here
                    var content = '<span id="tf_zoom" class="tf_zoom"><\/span>';
                    content     +='<img src="' +           $tf_bg_images.eq(current).attr('longdesc') + '" alt="Thumb' + (current+1) + '"/>';
                    $tf_thumbs.html(content);
                }
            });

            //we get the next image
            var $tf_bg_img_next = $tf_bg_images.eq(current),
                //its dimentions
                dim             = getImageDim($tf_bg_img_next),
                //the top should be one that makes the image out of the viewport
                //the image should be positioned up or down depending on the direction
                    top = (dir == 'tb')?$(window).height() + 'px':-parseFloat(dim.height,10) + 'px';

            //set the returned values and show the next image   
                $tf_bg_img_next.css({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    left    : dim.left,
                    top     : top
                }).show();

            //now slide it to the viewport
                $tf_bg_img_next.stop().animate({
                    top     : dim.top
                },700);

            //we want the old image to slide in the same direction, out of the viewport
                var slideTo = (dir == 'tb')?-$tf_bg_img.height() + 'px':$(window).height() + 'px';
                $tf_bg_img.stop().animate({
                    top     : slideTo
                },700,function(){
                //hide it
                    $(this).hide();
                //the $tf_bg_img is now the shown image
                    $tf_bg_img  = $tf_bg_img_next;
                //show the description for the new image
                    $tf_content_wrapper.children()
                                       .eq(current)
                                       .show();
            });
                //hide the current description  
                    $tf_content_wrapper.children(':visible')
                                       .hide()

            }

            //animate the image to fit in the viewport
            function resize($img){
                var w_w = $(window).width(),
                    w_h = $(window).height(),
                    i_w = $img.width(),
                    i_h = $img.height(),
                    r_i = i_h / i_w,
                    new_w,new_h;

                if(i_w > i_h){
                    new_w   = w_w;
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;

                    if(new_h > w_h){
                        new_h   = w_h;
                        new_w   = w_h / r_i;
                    }
                }   
                else{
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;
                    new_w   = w_w;
                }

                $img.animate({
                    width   : new_w + 'px',
                    height  : new_h + 'px',
                    top     : '0px',
                    left    : '0px'
                },350);
            }

            //get dimentions of the image, 
            //in order to make it full size and centered
            function getImageDim($img){
                var w_w = $(window).width(),
                    w_h = $(window).height(),
                    r_w = w_h / w_w,
                    i_w = $img.width(),
                    i_h = $img.height(),
                    r_i = i_h / i_w,
                    new_w,new_h,
                    new_left,new_top;

                if(r_w > r_i){
                    new_h   = w_h;
                    new_w   = w_h / r_i;
                }
                else{
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;
                    new_w   = w_w;
                }


                return {
                    width   : new_w + 'px',
                    height  : new_h + 'px',
                    left    : (w_w - new_w) / 2 + 'px',
                    top     : (w_h - new_h) / 2 + 'px'
                };
                }
        });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Please only show relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to set a `setTimeout()` and make it execute the function handling the "mouseclick".

When the page has finished loading you could fire this line:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){
    scroll(tb);
}, 2000);
```

That'll change the picture after 2 seconds.

If you want it to continue you could do something like this:

```
//Fire this after page has finished loading
var timer = setTimeout(function(){
    autoChange("tb", 2000);
}, 2000);

//Put this somewhere else
function autoChange(dir, timeout){
    scroll(dir);
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        autoChange("tb", 2000);
    }, timeout);
}
```

That'll make the picture change every 2 seconds. When the user clicks to change the picture you could change the timeout to, say,  5 seconds before it starts to autoscroll every 2 seconds again.

Read up on `setTimeout()` at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Comment: The method is `setTimeout`, not `Timeout`.  Also you pass `setTimeout` functions, not strings (you *can* pass strings, but they get `eval`ed, which is bad).  You want to do: `var timer = Timeout(autoChange, 2000);`  Or `var timer = Timeout(function(){ autoChange(); }, 2000);`  I'd suggest the 2nd, you can pass a parameter to `autoChange`.  `var timer = Timeout(function(){ autoChange(tb, 2000); }, 2000);`

Comment: Here are some (better) docs for `setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: `setTimeout` only executes the function once. We're looking for `setInterval` here.

Comment: @lbstr: In his `autoChange`, he calls `setTimeout` again.

Comment: Oh, also, your `var timer` inside `autoChange`, is setting a *local* `timer` variable, not editing the *global* one.

Comment: @Rocket d'oh! sorry I didn't read carefully -- you're right. `setInterval` is still cleaner than that.

Comment: Thank you @jonstodle, i just add 5 images and the code you gave me but nothing change, maybe i paste the code in the wrong place? would you mind take a look? http://www.luischales.com

Comment: @Rocket The previous `timer` variable is most likely not global either, so he'll have to decalre it once more. Or he could of course just set a global one.

Comment: @lbstr Wasn't aware of `setInterval`, but thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @lchales You should put the first line with the code that executes when the page has finished loading; which looks to be you `init()` function.

Comment: Seems @Rocket cleaned up my code a bit :) (I'm a sloppy coder :/)

Comment: @JonStødle my friend thank you so much but still nothing happens, i just upload it again. Sorry if i still do it wrong but my brain is fried right now.

Comment: @lchales Try changing the `tb` in the function calls to `"tb"` (with the quote marks). I'm not sure if javascript sees the difference, but that seems to be the only thing that's different from the rest of your code

Comment: AAAAAAWWWWWWWW @JonStødle you are the man, thank you my friend.

Comment: @lchales I'm taking that it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any simple...

No :)

Take a look at the `setTimeout()` function. Maybe this could help:

- http://blog.agrafix.net/2011/10/javascript-timers-mit-jquery/
- http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down this code until you see `MY ANSWER!!!!!!!!`

**EDIT:**
I've pasted some udpated code. Try this again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    /*
    the images preload plugin
    */
    (function($) {
        $.fn.preload = function(options) {
            var opts    = $.extend({}, $.fn.preload.defaults, options),
                o       = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, this.data()) : opts;
            var c       = this.length,
                l       = 0;
            return this.each(function() {
                var $i  = $(this);
                $('<img/>').load(function(i){
                    ++l;
                    if(l == c) o.onComplete();
                }).attr('src',$i.attr('src'));  
            });
        };
        $.fn.preload.defaults = {
            onComplete  : function(){return false;}
        };
    })(jQuery);
//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        var $tf_bg              = $('#tf_bg'),
            $tf_bg_images       = $tf_bg.find('img'),
            $tf_bg_img          = $tf_bg_images.eq(0),
            $tf_thumbs          = $('#tf_thumbs'),
            total               = $tf_bg_images.length,
            current             = 0,
            $tf_content_wrapper = $('#tf_content_wrapper'),
            $tf_next            = $('#tf_next'),
            $tf_prev            = $('#tf_prev'),
            $tf_loading         = $('#tf_loading');


        //preload the images                
        $tf_bg_images.preload({
            onComplete  : function(){
                $tf_loading.hide();
                init();
            }
        });


        //shows the first image and initializes events
        function init(){
            //get dimentions for the image, based on the windows size
            var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
            //set the returned values and show the image
            $tf_bg_img.css({
                width   : dim.width,
                height  : dim.height,
                left    : dim.left,
                top     : dim.top
            }).fadeIn();

            //resizing the window resizes the $tf_bg_img
            $(window).bind('resize',function(){
                var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                $tf_bg_img.css({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    left    : dim.left,
                    top     : dim.top
                });
            });

            // MY ANSWER!!!!!!!!!!
            // Click next every 5000 ms (5 sec). 
            setInterval(function(){
                $tf_next.click();
            }, 5000);
        }

        //expand and fit the image to the screen
        $('#tf_zoom').live('click', function(){
            if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                return false;

            var $this   = $(this);
            if($this.hasClass('tf_zoom')){
                resize($tf_bg_img);
                $this.addClass('tf_fullscreen')
                     .removeClass('tf_zoom');
            }
            else{
                var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                $tf_bg_img.animate({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    top     : dim.top,
                    left    : dim.left
                },350);
                $this.addClass('tf_zoom')
                     .removeClass('tf_fullscreen'); 
            }
        });

        //click the arrow down, scrolls down
        $tf_next.bind('click',function(){
            if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                return false;
            scroll('tb');
        });

        //click the arrow up, scrolls up
        $tf_prev.bind('click',function(){
            if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                return false;
            scroll('bt');
        });

        //mousewheel events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up
        $(document).mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
            if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                return false;

            if(delta > 0)
                scroll('bt');
            else
                scroll('tb');
            return false;
        });

        //key events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up
        $(document).keydown(function(e){
            if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                return false;

            switch(e.which){
                case 38:    
                    scroll('bt');
                    break;  

                case 40:    
                    scroll('tb');
                    break;
            }
        });


            //show next / prev image
        function scroll(dir){
            //if dir is "tb" (top -> bottom) increment current, 
            //else if "bt" decrement it
            current = (dir == 'tb')?current + 1:current - 1;

            //we want a circular slideshow, 
            //so we need to check the limits of current
            if(current == total) current = 0;
            else if(current < 0) current = total - 1;

            //flip the thumb
            $tf_thumbs.flip({
                direction   : dir,
                speed       : 400,
                onBefore    : function(){
                    //the new thumb is set here
                    var content = '<span id="tf_zoom" class="tf_zoom"><\/span>';
                    content     +='<img src="' + $tf_bg_images.eq(current).attr('longdesc') + '" alt="Thumb' + (current+1) + '"/>';
                    $tf_thumbs.html(content);
                }
            });

            //we get the next image
            var $tf_bg_img_next = $tf_bg_images.eq(current),
                //its dimentions
                dim             = getImageDim($tf_bg_img_next),
                //the top should be one that makes the image out of the viewport
                //the image should be positioned up or down depending on the direction
                top = (dir == 'tb')?$(window).height() + 'px':-parseFloat(dim.height,10) + 'px';

            //set the returned values and show the next image   
            $tf_bg_img_next.css({
                width   : dim.width,
                height  : dim.height,
                left    : dim.left,
                top     : top
            }).show();

            //now slide it to the viewport
            $tf_bg_img_next.stop().animate({
                top     : dim.top
            },700);

            //we want the old image to slide in the same direction, out of the viewport
            var slideTo = (dir == 'tb')?-$tf_bg_img.height() + 'px':$(window).height() + 'px';
            $tf_bg_img.stop().animate({
                    top     : slideTo
                },700,function(){
                //hide it
                    $(this).hide();
                //the $tf_bg_img is now the shown image
                    $tf_bg_img  = $tf_bg_img_next;
                //show the description for the new image
                    $tf_content_wrapper.children()
                                       .eq(current)
                                       .show();
            });
            //hide the current description  
                $tf_content_wrapper.children(':visible')
                                   .hide()

        }

        //animate the image to fit in the viewport
        function resize($img){
            var w_w = $(window).width(),
                w_h = $(window).height(),
                i_w = $img.width(),
                i_h = $img.height(),
                r_i = i_h / i_w,
                new_w,new_h;

            if(i_w > i_h){
                new_w   = w_w;
                new_h   = w_w * r_i;

                if(new_h > w_h){
                    new_h   = w_h;
                    new_w   = w_h / r_i;
                }
            }   
            else{
                new_h   = w_w * r_i;
                new_w   = w_w;
            }

            $img.animate({
                width   : new_w + 'px',
                height  : new_h + 'px',
                top     : '0px',
                left    : '0px'
            },350);
        }

        //get dimentions of the image, 
        //in order to make it full size and centered
        function getImageDim($img){
            var w_w = $(window).width(),
                w_h = $(window).height(),
                r_w = w_h / w_w,
                i_w = $img.width(),
                i_h = $img.height(),
                r_i = i_h / i_w,
                new_w,new_h,
                new_left,new_top;

            if(r_w > r_i){
                new_h   = w_h;
                new_w   = w_h / r_i;
            }
            else{
                new_h   = w_w * r_i;
                new_w   = w_w;
            }


            return {
                width   : new_w + 'px',
                height  : new_h + 'px',
                left    : (w_w - new_w) / 2 + 'px',
                top     : (w_h - new_h) / 2 + 'px'
            };
        }
    });​
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Note that I included all of the code because our questioner likely won't know *where* to place our suggested code. The first line of the OP states that they don't know anything about code, so let's be accommodating here.

Comment: thank you @lbstr, i found your answer but is not working,

Comment: i just upload it you could see it here http://www.luischales.com

Comment: @lchales I checked the site and you didn't have my answer in there. You had Jon Stodle's. Anyway, I've updated my code. Copy/paste the code above and see if it works.

Comment: @lchales beautiful pictures on your site btw

Comment: thank you so much and thanks for the comments on my work.

Answer (score 0):

You can hijack the next arrow click event along with [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $tf_next.trigger('click');
}, 2500); // Change 2500 to whatever miliseconds delay you want
```

Good luck!